# Google Earth Engine unequal histogram values

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, histogram, image-pyramids, vegetation-index

I am creating histograms in Earth Engine of pixel values of cloud masked EVI from different years using Landsat 8. For each of the layers I create, I use an identical geometry to clip the output, but the pixel counts in my histograms vary from each other considerably. Below is a picture of several of these histograms exported to excel and displayed as line graphs to make them easier to see.

An extract of my code is below, the full thing consists of the same code repeated several times but with different years instead of '2018' in each section.

Why is this happening? I understand that because of cloud masks the total pixels in each output will vary slightly, but that would produce nothing on this magnitude as it is only very small areas which are masked. I also made certain that my pyramiding policy was the same throughout. I really have no idea why this is happening!

[image: EVI counts - each line is a different year]

```
var forest = BROADLEAF.merge(MIXED).filterBounds(geometry4);
////////////////CLOUD MASK////////////////
function maskL8sr(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
//////////////2018/////////////////////////
var collection18 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-08-31')
    .filterBounds(geometry4)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false)
    .map(maskL8sr);

var composite18 = collection18.median();

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(composite18, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var evi2018 = composite18.expression(
  '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
    'NIR': composite18.select('B5'),
    'RED': composite18.select('B4'),
    'BLUE': composite18.select('B2')
});

var evi2018real = evi2018.clip(forest);

var histogram5 = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: evi2018real, 
  region: geometry4, 
  scale: 30, 
  maxPixels: 1e13})
    .setSeriesNames(['18']);

print(histogram5);
Map.addLayer(evi2018real, {bands: ['constant'], min: 0, max: 0.75}, "2018");
```